# Why bounding doesn't work in this Google MAP API?

Tags: google-maps

If I do:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=kemayoran&sensor=false This is the result I want if not for the fact I want this to work when visitors type kem  instead of kemayoran.

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Kemayoran",
               "short_name" : "Kemayoran",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Jakarta Pusat",
               "short_name" : "Jakarta Pusat",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Jakarta",
               "short_name" : "Jakarta",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Jakarta Capital Region",
               "short_name" : "Jakarta Capital Region",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Indonesia",
               "short_name" : "ID",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Kemayoran, Jakarta, Indonesia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -6.14935190,
                  "lng" : 106.8857620
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -6.171493900000001,
                  "lng" : 106.84546290
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -6.16165420,
               "lng" : 106.8550150
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -6.14935190,
                  "lng" : 106.8857620
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -6.171493900000001,
                  "lng" : 106.84546290
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Kemayoran",
               "short_name" : "Kemayoran",
               "types" : [ "train_station", "transit_station", "establishment" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Jalan Garuda",
               "short_name" : "Jalan Garuda",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pasar Baru",
               "short_name" : "Pasar Baru",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Sawah Besar",
               "short_name" : "Sawah Besar",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Jakarta Pusat",
               "short_name" : "Jakarta Pusat",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Jakarta",
               "short_name" : "Jakarta",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Jakarta Capital Region",
               "short_name" : "Jakarta Capital Region",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Indonesia",
               "short_name" : "ID",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "10710",
               "short_name" : "10710",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Kemayoran, Jalan Garuda, Jakarta 10710, Indonesia",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -6.16204140,
               "lng" : 106.84154990
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -6.160692419708497,
                  "lng" : 106.8428988802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -6.163390380291502,
                  "lng" : 106.8402009197085
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "train_station", "transit_station", "establishment" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Kemayoran",
               "short_name" : "Kemayoran",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kemayoran",
               "short_name" : "Kemayoran",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Jakarta Pusat",
               "short_name" : "Jakarta Pusat",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Jakarta",
               "short_name" : "Jakarta",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Jakarta Capital Region",
               "short_name" : "Jakarta Capital Region",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Indonesia",
               "short_name" : "ID",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "10620",
               "short_name" : "10620",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Kemayoran, Jakarta 10620, Indonesia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -6.1602730,
                  "lng" : 106.8572680
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -6.1664210,
                  "lng" : 106.851820
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -6.16165420,
               "lng" : 106.8550150
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -6.1602730,
                  "lng" : 106.8572680
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -6.1664210,
                  "lng" : 106.851820
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Kemayoran",
               "short_name" : "Kemayoran",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Krembangan",
               "short_name" : "Krembangan",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Surabaya",
               "short_name" : "Surabaya",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "East Java",
               "short_name" : "East Java",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Indonesia",
               "short_name" : "ID",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "60176",
               "short_name" : "60176",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Kemayoran, Surabaya 60176, Indonesia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -7.2369960,
                  "lng" : 112.7333040
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -7.2465120,
                  "lng" : 112.726760
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -7.2417540,
               "lng" : 112.7300320
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -7.2369960,
                  "lng" : 112.7333040
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -7.2465120,
                  "lng" : 112.726760
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Kemayoran",
               "short_name" : "Kemayoran",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bangkalan",
               "short_name" : "Bangkalan",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bangkalan Regency",
               "short_name" : "Bangkalan Regency",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "East Java",
               "short_name" : "East Java",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Indonesia",
               "short_name" : "ID",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "69116",
               "short_name" : "69116",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Kemayoran, Bangkalan 69116, Indonesia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -7.0243290,
                  "lng" : 112.7483040
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -7.039670,
                  "lng" : 112.7349340
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -7.031263999999999,
               "lng" : 112.7417250
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -7.0243290,
                  "lng" : 112.7483040
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -7.039670,
                  "lng" : 112.7349340
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I got several kemayoran.

If I do:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=kemayoran&sensor=false&bounds=-6,106|-5,107

I got kemayoran. But only one even though all the other kemayoran is well within the bounds.

I specified the bound correctly on first query because as you can all see, the latitude logitude of kemayoran is well within the bounds  -6,106|-5,107

If I do

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=kemay&sensor=false&bounds=-6,106|-5,107

I got Kemnay instead of kemayoran.

Compare that with this private API:
http://maps.google.com/maps/suggest?q=kemay&cp=2&hl=en&gl=&v=2&clid=1&json=a&ll=-6.230664,106.55365&spn=1,1&src=1&num=20&numps=0

The result is precisely what I want except that it doesn't give latitude and longitude, not to mention being a private API.

So, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bounds is only a way to bias the search results as explained in [Google's documentation of the webservice](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=sv-SE#Viewports).  Since you specify a search string of "Kemay" it finds the exact match in Scotland.  However, as observed when you type in the exact string it finds what you're looking for.

**EDIT:**

It really sounds like you're looking for a functionality like the places autocomplete feature (either [via webservice](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#location_biasing), or better yet via the [javascript library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete)).  That one seems to give more accurate results while typing in a partial string.

Comment: I know. But why if I type kemayoran within my bounds only one kemayorans show up instead of 2?

Comment: I am well aware of that before asking this question. I want something that behaves like  http://maps.google.com/maps/suggest?q=kemay&cp=2&hl=en&gl=&v=2&clid=1&json=a&ll=-6.230664,106.55365&spn=1,1&src=1&num=20&numps=0 also

Comment: Tried doesn't work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598477/why-i-failed-to-access-google-autocomplete-api-even-though-i-have-provided-a-key I don't even know if the API is still functioning.

Comment: Selected for lack of better answer. Also you point out that webservice.