# Why I failed to access google autocomplete API even though I have provided a Key

Tags: api, google-maps

I tried to access

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=Amoeba&types=establishment&location=37.76999,-122.44696&radius=500&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyAqTo6fgd8zK8rVNxvSO8WsEkBxRxd3PIE

I got access denied.

As you can see, I have provided some key API. Maybe I supplied different key

Here is the problem.

I got my key from
https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:299025262955:services

I enabled all these services

Ad Exchange Buyer API           Courtesy limit: 1,000 requests/day

```
Google Maps API v2          Courtesy limit: 25,000 requests/day • Pricing
Google Maps API v3          Courtesy limit: 25,000 requests/day • Pricing
Google Maps Coordinate API          Courtesy limit: 1,000 requests/day
Google Play Android Developer API           Courtesy limit: 15,000 requests/day
Google+ API             Courtesy limit: 10,000 requests/day
Static Maps API             Courtesy limit: 25,000 requests/day • Pricing
```

Moreover, I read somewhere that google map API 3 does not use key at all to further add confusion.

So, what API key I should have been using anyway? Google API Key? Google Map API Key? Google Map version 3 API key? What?

I access it directly so there is no referrer. Is that the issue? The setting for referrer is:

Referers:
Any referer allowed

I wonder if that includes blank referrer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem is. Google AutoComplete is part of google places instead of google map. So I need to turn on google places feature.

It still sucks though because it doesn't tell me the latitude and longitude of places found.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you solve somehow how to get latitude and longitude of places? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems the key you specified is wrong.
I swapped the key to mine, then it worked.

[image]

---

You should use the key which appears at "Simple API Access" in "API Access" page.
[image]

Comment: So the key is right, but the true problem is I have to turn on Google Place.

Answer (score 0):

using google place API may cause charge. you are limited to only 1000 request per day and this will be extended to 25000 per day if you validate a credit card. exeeding this limits will cause you charge or the user will notre receive response from the service. be aware of the details and google policies. good luck